# How to add a listview to a column and then divide the remaining space (if any) with 1/3 above the list and 2/3 below the list

Tags: listview, flutter

I am trying to do a screen that holds a "short" list, 5-6 items, and once the list is in place, any remaining space should be divided 1/3 above the list and 2/3 below the list.

Its causing me problems that the ListView.builder it self sits in an Expanded, so the list ends up dividing all of the space with the top and bottom.

It should make sure that the entire list is visible, and then divide the remaining space as described.

What makes it even more tricky, that I had not even thought about yet, is if the list is on a very small phone, where I might need to be able to scroll the list.

I have been playing around with a tree that basically has a Column at the top, then:

- Expanded(flex:1)
- Expanded(child: ListVIew.builder)
- Expanded(flex:2)

This splits the entire screen, and the list does not have a guarantee to be fully shown.

I also tried using Spacers, and even adding a Align(Aligment.offset) which did not really work wither.

```
    class OverviewPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var edition = Provider.of<Edition>(context);
    return Column(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max, children: [
      Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(margin_20)),
      Expanded(flex: 1,),
      Expanded(
            child: Align(
                alignment: Alignment(0.0, -0.0),
                child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: edition.editionContent.articles.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return OverviewItem(EditionPage.overview, articleNo: index);
                })),
      ),
      Expanded(flex: 2,),
    ]);
  }
}
```

So, the first challenge is to layout the list, and split any remaining space with 1/3 above the list and 2/3 below the list.

And ideally, this would also work on very small screens. Meaning there would be no space to divide, but the list would be scrollable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this you can do what you need, uses `Spacer` instead `Expanded` like this:

```
       Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Spacer(flex: 1),
          ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: 6,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Text('item number $index');
              }),
          Spacer(flex: 2),
        ],
      )
```

this should show you the screen like you need it.

Comment: doooh.... this was my first approach literally. BUT I forgot shrinkWrap: true...thx!